# Current Quarter - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How do I filter for **current** **quarter** in this query in postgres ?

```
SELECT dept, year, qtr
, sum(sales)  filter (where year=(select max(year) from Department where dept is not null) and quartal=(select max(qtr) from Department where year = (select max(year) from Department where Dept is not null)))::decimal AS Sales
from Department
group by dept
       , year
       , qtr;
```

Output

select max(qtr) - This currently fetched for me Q4 2021 data since that is populated. Instead I want to based on current quarter Q2 select data.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Gallop please provide sample input and output.

Comment: You mean like `where year = 2021 and qtr = 3`?

Comment: Current quarter data is to be selected..thanks based on now() ?

Comment: Get quarter from now(): `extract('quarter' from now())`

Comment: Thanks...how about previous quarter based on now() is that possible ? Thanks